# Bootstrap 4 Navbar does not line up correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]I using Bootstrap 4 and am having some issues with my Navbar.  The issue I am facing is on my dropdown, "Services" is not lines up with the rest of the navbar. I have done a lot of research but I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am pretty sure it is something sinple that I am over looking.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.dropdown {
  padding-top: 3%;
  ;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.back1 {
  background-image: url(./assets/images/back1.png);
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 0%;
}

.back2 {
  background-image: url(./assets/images/back2.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.heroText,
.heroButton,
.heroSubText {
  padding-top: .4em;
}

.howItWorks {
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

#textColor {
  color: #102D47;
}

.heroIcon {
  color: #102D47;
  padding-top: 5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.heroText {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #102D47;
}

.heroButton {
  background-color: #102D47;
  color: white;
}

.heroSubText {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #102D47;
}

.howItWorks {
  background-image: url(./assets/images/debut_light.png);
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

.bottomhero {
  color: #102D47;
}

.heroFeatures {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #102D47;
}

.subjectHeadRight,
.subjectHeadLeft {
  padding-top: 1.9em;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #102D47;
}

.subjectHeadFooter {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.footerText {
  color: white;
}

.subjectHeadContact {
  padding-top: 1%;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #102D47;
}

.videoSection {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.page-footer {
  background-color: #102D47;
}


/* Learn More Section */

.mainArea {
  background-color: #20812d;
}

.signUpBox {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
}

.signUpHead {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-top: 4%;
}

.signUpSub {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: -4%;
}

.teamPic {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.peopleImg {
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: lightgray solid 1px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .subjectHeadRight,
  .subjectHeadLeft,
  .howContentLeft,
  .howContentRight {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .howImg {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .subjectHeadRight,
  .subjectHeadLeft {
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .howContentLeft,
  .howContentRight {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .heroText {
    font-size: 72px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="./assets/images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Service Lead</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center back2">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-auto"><img src="./assets/images/servicelead-logo-150.png" alt="Service Lead Logo"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
      <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " id="textColor" href="#">Industries</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="textColor" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Services</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">Website Design</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">SEO</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">PPC</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">Call Booking</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">Facebook Marketing</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">Review Pro</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">... and More!</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="textColor" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="textColor" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="textColor" href="tel:6193688116">Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- Navbar End-->


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">

    <!-- Footer Links -->
    <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">

      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="row">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">

          <!-- Content -->
          <h5 class="subjectHeadFooter">About ServiceLead</h5>
          <p class="footerText">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 footerText">
                ServiceLead is built to help today's service contractors better manage their businesses. We are here to help you convert online leads to booked service appointments. Find out why so many contractors trust ServiceLead to grow their business!
              </div>
            </div>
          </p>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="subjectHeadFooter">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled ">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="subjectHeadFooter">Address</h5>

          <p class="address footerText">
            ServiceLead
          </p>


        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->

    </div>
    <!-- Footer Links -->

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3 footerText">© 2020 Copyright:
      <a href="https://servicelead.com/"> ServiceLead.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->

  </footer>

  <!-- Footer End-->

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I made a .dropdown class and made changes to it in css. That caused the issue and is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this, that should solve the issue

```
.dropdown {
  padding-top: 3%;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

/*
.dropdown {
  padding-top: 3%; /* REMOVE this 
}
*/

.navbar {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.back1 {
  background-image: url(./assets/images/back1.png);
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 0%;
}

.back2 {
  background-image: url(./assets/images/back2.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.heroText,
.heroButton,
.heroSubText {
  padding-top: .4em;
}

.howItWorks {
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

#textColor {
  color: #102D47;
}

.heroIcon {
  color: #102D47;
  padding-top: 5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.heroText {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #102D47;
}

.heroButton {
  background-color: #102D47;
  color: white;
}

.heroSubText {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #102D47;
}

.howItWorks {
  background-image: url(./assets/images/debut_light.png);
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

.bottomhero {
  color: #102D47;
}

.heroFeatures {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #102D47;
}

.subjectHeadRight,
.subjectHeadLeft {
  padding-top: 1.9em;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #102D47;
}

.subjectHeadFooter {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.footerText {
  color: white;
}

.subjectHeadContact {
  padding-top: 1%;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #102D47;
}

.videoSection {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.page-footer {
  background-color: #102D47;
}


/* Learn More Section */

.mainArea {
  background-color: #20812d;
}

.signUpBox {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
}

.signUpHead {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-top: 4%;
}

.signUpSub {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: -4%;
}

.teamPic {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.peopleImg {
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: lightgray solid 1px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .subjectHeadRight,
  .subjectHeadLeft,
  .howContentLeft,
  .howContentRight {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .howImg {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .subjectHeadRight,
  .subjectHeadLeft {
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .howContentLeft,
  .howContentRight {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .heroText {
    font-size: 72px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="./assets/images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Service Lead</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center back2">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-auto"><img src="./assets/images/servicelead-logo-150.png" alt="Service Lead Logo"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
      <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " id="textColor" href="#">Industries</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="textColor" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Services</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">Website Design</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">SEO</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">PPC</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">Call Booking</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">Facebook Marketing</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">Review Pro</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="textColor">... and More!</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="textColor" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="textColor" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="textColor" href="tel:6193688116">Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- Navbar End-->


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer class="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">

    <!-- Footer Links -->
    <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">

      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="row">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">

          <!-- Content -->
          <h5 class="subjectHeadFooter">About ServiceLead</h5>
          <p class="footerText">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 footerText">
                ServiceLead is built to help today's service contractors better manage their businesses. We are here to help you convert online leads to booked service appointments. Find out why so many contractors trust ServiceLead to grow their business!
              </div>
            </div>
          </p>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="subjectHeadFooter">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled ">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">

          <!-- Links -->
          <h5 class="subjectHeadFooter">Address</h5>

          <p class="address footerText">
            ServiceLead
          </p>


        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->

    </div>
    <!-- Footer Links -->

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3 footerText">© 2020 Copyright:
      <a href="https://servicelead.com/"> ServiceLead.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->

  </footer>

  <!-- Footer End-->

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```